# How to get the form action attr with Vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js

How to get the action attribute of form with Vue.js?

```
<form action="xyz">
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you go the way with plain Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Either use JS/Jquery to locate the form and get the action:

```
//Jquery
$('#form_id').attr('action');

//plain JS
document.getElementById('form_id').action;
```

Or you can put the action in the Vue object instead of directly on the form:

```
//your Vue object
{
    data:function(){
        return {
            submitUrl: '/path/to/action'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can post to `this.submitUrl`